# Fixing font - some capital letters (e.g. 'Å', 'Ä', 'Ö') cut off from the top

Tags: fonts, font-forge

First of all apologies for any mistakes in this text (for example terms or wrong assunptions). I'm no typography expert. I just think changing a font should be possible. That's why I'm asking for information here.

So, I have the font Sofia Pro, which has problems. Both Regular and Medium.
I don't know what is exactly the problem, but I think the baseline is too high.

When using the font (for example in my iOS app), it doesn't seem vertically aligned in the middle, it's too high.
When using `Å`, `Ä`, `Ö`, etc., the top is cut off.
Opening the font in Apple Font Book, shows it like this (when selectinng text):

[image: Sofia Pro Regular]

As you can see, `ABCD` seems too high, as well as `4567`.
`cdefg` / `yzåäö` seem to be fine, but `ZÅÄÖ` isn't even completely in the selection.

I also downloaded Font Forge, which shows me this:

[image: Font Forge]

So basically the same problem as Font Book.

First of all, what is the problem here? Should the baseline be lower? Will then letters such as `cdefg` still be fine?
Or is the 'ascent' just not high enough?

Would fixing this be possible in Font Forge, or do you have other suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to GDSE. I suspect (although I am no expert in such things) that this is not a problem with the font, and is possibly the way you are implementing it in your app.  If you google "fonts cropped in iOS" you will see there are references to such problems - nearly all of which have been resolved with coding solutions. So, I'd suggest this is probably off topic for GDSE. Perhaps you could flag your question and ask for it to be migrated to Super User.  Note also that there are potential legal problems when altering fonts - since the font license may not allow it.

Comment: No problem, the font works just as it is supposed to work.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
@BillyKerr Actually, it is a problem of the font. The first photo is when I open the font in Mac's 'Font Book' application, even there the top is cropped off. I have other fonts as well, which work just fine, even the Å, Ä, Ö. I know there are solution for the app, I used some of them, but it's a problem that keeps coming back and it seems more effort to fix it in code than fixing the font.

Comment: i have the same problem with Sofia Pro. i loaded it to fontforge and it fixed one problem (button text alignment) but created another (text alignment in neighboring columns).